# What are the words and meaning that compose the title of Glasslip?

Tags: glasslip

Is it glass + lip?
Is it glass + slip?

The Japanese title is

グラスリップ - it is in katakana, so definitely is a foreign word.

So, the title means lips made of glass, or slipping on glass?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure about the meaning behind the name, but I'm pretty sure it is pronounced Glass + lip, mainly due to this image:

[image: http://animeinspirations.com/attachments/vlcsnap-2014-07-04-17h19m17s62-png.959/]

Source:
http://animeinspirations.com/threads/is-there-some-hidden-meaning-to-the-title-glasslip.378/

Answer (score 0):

Glasslip is presented as a single word, and it is logical to suppose that "glass lip" is what the anime was going for. This makes sense, since here, “lip” can mean “a projecting edge on a container or other hollow object”. Then, "Glass lip” can describe to the edges of glass surface, such as a bead, where the glass bends around and causes light passing through to bend in strange ways, distorting the image [1].

**Sources**

1. https://infinitemirai.wordpress.com/2015/09/14/a-glasslip-analysis-deciphering-what-glasslip-intended-to-be-about-through-its-opening-sequence-and-its-impact-on-viewer-expectations/